# Find the matrix representation relative to the standard bases

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $T : P_{2}(C) \to  C^3$ be a linear transformation such that
$$T(a + bx + cx^2) = (a, a + b, a + b + c)$$

Find the matrix representation $[T]$ relative to the standard bases.

If standard basis for $R^3$,

$T(1,0,0)=(1,0,0)$

$T(0,1,0)=(1,1,0)$

$T(0,0,1)=(1,1,1)$

Therefore,
$[T]$ = \begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\1&1&0\\1&1&1\end{bmatrix}

But it is the same with $C^3$ ?

Comment: Welcome to MathSE. Can you show your attempts for to solve this problem?

Comment: If standard basis for $R^3$
$T(1,0,0) = (1, 0, 0)$
$T(0,1,0) = (1, 1, 0)$
$T(0,0,1) = (1, 1, 1)$

Therefore,
$[T] =  \begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\1&1&0\\1&1&1\end{bmatrix} $

Comment: Ok, please add that attempt in your post. Also, what's mean $C$? Is $C$ the complex field?

Comment: yes complex field

Answer (score 1):

First, we need to analyze two case:

1. $\mathbb{C}_{\mathbb{R}}$: Complex space over $\mathbb{R}$.
2. $\mathbb{C}_{\mathbb{C}}$: Complex space over $\mathbb{C}$.

Then, the answer dependes if in your problem $T:P_{2}(\mathbb{C}_{\mathbb{C}})\to \mathbb{C}_{\mathbb{C}}^{3}$ or $T:P_{2}(\mathbb{C}_{\mathbb{R}})\to \mathbb{C}_{\mathbb{R}}^{3}$.

Suppose for example the second case, also is well-know that $\mathbb{C}_{\mathbb{R}}\cong \mathbb{R}^{2}$ and $\mathbb{C}_{\mathbb{R}}^{3}\cong  \mathbb{R}^{6}$. (In general $\mathbb{C}_{\mathbb{R}}^{n} \cong \mathbb{R}^{2n}$). So, we have that $[T]_{\beta_{1}\to \beta_{2}}$ be a matrix of order $\dim(\mathbb{C}_{\mathbb{R}}^{3})\times \dim(P_{2}(\mathbb{C}_{\mathbb{R}}))$.

Now, in the first case:  $T:P_{2}(\mathbb{C}_{\mathbb{C}})\to \mathbb{C}_{\mathbb{C}}^{3}$, we have that your approach is correct. Indeed $$[T]=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 & 1\end{pmatrix}$$